# form validation dont check all added inputes

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

i have this two component in my nextjs component so in the handel next i checked if the user add a form of inputs(door inputs),if not it toast an error and i also checked if the user had filed the doors he added but my function only checked the first door it does not check the second door until i write and delete what i write, it just like it does not recognise the added inputs
the scenario i want is to checked every door every input that exest on the user screen
Port:

```
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { db,auth } from "../config/firebase";
import { setDoc, collection, doc,addDoc,getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import Form from "../components/form";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';


export default function Porte({onNext}) {
  const [duplicatedComponents, setDuplicatedComponents] = useState([]);
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [userId, setuserId] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the user is logged in
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setuserId(user.uid); // Set the user's email in state
        Cookies.set('uid', user.uid)
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe(); // Cleanup the event listener
  }, []);

  const addDuplicatedComponent = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    setDuplicatedComponents((prevComponents) => [...prevComponents, count + 1]);
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };
      const appartementKey = `Appartement ${count + 1}`;
      updatedFormData[appartementKey] = {}; // Create an empty object for the new "Appartement"

      return updatedFormData;
    });
  };
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// const retrieveProjects = async () => {
//   try {
//     // Check if the userId variable is defined
//     if (!userId) {
//       console.error("User ID is not defined");
//       return;
//     }

//     // Create a reference to the user's projects collection
//     const projectsCollectionRef = collection(db, "users", userId, "projects");

//     // Listen for changes to the projects collection
//     onSnapshot(projectsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
//       querySnapshot.forEach((projectDoc) => {
//         console.log(`Project ID: ${projectDoc.id}`);

//         // Retrieve the apartments collection inside the current project document
//         const apartmentsCollectionRef = collection(
//           projectDoc.ref,
//           "apartments"
//         );

//         // Listen for changes to the apartments collection
//         onSnapshot(apartmentsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
//           querySnapshot.forEach((apartmentDoc) => {
//             console.log(`  Apartment ID: ${apartmentDoc.id}`);

//             // Retrieve the doors collection inside the current apartment document
//             const doorsCollectionRef = collection(
//               apartmentDoc.ref,
//               "Doors"
//             );

//             // Listen for changes to the doors collection
//             onSnapshot(doorsCollectionRef, (querySnapshot) => {
//               querySnapshot.forEach((doorDoc) => {
//                 console.log(
//                   `    Door ID: ${doorDoc.id}, data:`,
//                   doorDoc.data()
//                 );
//               });
//             });
//           });
//         });
//       });
//     });

//     console.log("Data retrieved successfully");
//   } catch (error) {
//     console.error("Error retrieving data:", error);
//   }
// };
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const handleDeleteApparetment = () => {
    if (duplicatedComponents.length > 0) {
      setDuplicatedComponents((prevComponents) => prevComponents.slice(0, -1));
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
      setFormData((prevFormData) => {
        const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };
        const appartementKeys = Object.keys(updatedFormData);
        const lastAppartementKey = appartementKeys[appartementKeys.length - 1];
        delete updatedFormData[lastAppartementKey];
        return updatedFormData;
      });
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteForm = (appartementNumber, porteIndex) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };
      const appartementKey = `Appartement ${appartementNumber}`;
      const currentAppartement = updatedFormData[appartementKey];

      if (currentAppartement) {
        delete currentAppartement[`porte_${porteIndex}`];
      }

      return updatedFormData;
    });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (appartementNumber, porteIndex, type, value) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };
  
      const appartementKey = `Appartement ${appartementNumber}`;
      const currentAppartement = { ...updatedFormData[appartementKey] };
  
      const currentPorte = {
        ...currentAppartement[`porte_${porteIndex}`],
        [`porte_${type}`]: value,
      };
  
      currentAppartement[`porte_${porteIndex}`] = currentPorte;
  
      updatedFormData[appartementKey] = currentAppartement;
  
      return updatedFormData;
    });
  };
  
  
  const handleNextClick = () => {
   
    if (Object.keys(formData).length === 0) {
      toast.error('Please add at least one Appartement');
      return;
    }
  
    let hasError = false;
  
    Object.entries(formData).forEach(([appartementKey, appartement]) => {
      if (Object.keys(appartement).length === 0) {
        toast.error(`Appartement ${appartementKey} does not have any doors`);
        hasError = true;
      } else {
        Object.entries(appartement).forEach(([porteKey, porte]) => {
          const requiredProperties = ['height', 'thickness', 'width'];
  
          const isMissingProperties = requiredProperties.some(
            (property) => porte[`porte_${property}`] === undefined || porte[`porte_${property}`] === ''
          );
  
          if (isMissingProperties) {
            toast.error(`Door ${porteKey} in Appartement ${appartementKey} is missing required properties or has empty values`);
            hasError = true;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  
    if (hasError) {
      return;
    }
  
    toast.success('All doors are filled');
    console.log('Data is valid. Proceed to next step');
    // onNext(formData);
  };

  // const handleNext = async (formData) => {
  //   try {
  //     // Filter out the empty objects from the form data
  //     const filteredFormData = Object.fromEntries(
  //       Object.entries(formData).filter(
  //         ([key, value]) => Object.keys(value).length !== 0
  //       )
  //     );
  
  //     // Create a reference to the user's projects collection
  //     const projectsCollectionRef = collection(db, "users", userId, "projects");
  
  //     // Add a new project document with an auto-incrementing ID
  //     const newProjectRef = await addDoc(projectsCollectionRef, {});
  
  //     // Create a reference to the apartments collection inside the new project document
  //     const apartmentsCollectionRef = collection(newProjectRef, "apartments");
  
  //     // Loop through the filtered form data and store the apartments in the collection
  //     for (const apartmentId in filteredFormData) {
  //       const apartment = filteredFormData[apartmentId];
  
  //       // Create a document for the apartment
  //       const apartmentDocRef = doc(apartmentsCollectionRef, apartmentId);
  //       await setDoc(apartmentDocRef, {});
  
  //       // Loop through the doors and store them in the subcollection "Doors" of the current apartment document
  //       for (const doorId in apartment) {
  //         const door = apartment[doorId];
  
  //         // Create a document for the door
  //         const doorDocRef = doc(collection(apartmentDocRef, "Doors"), doorId);
  //         await setDoc(doorDocRef, door);
  //       }
  //     }
  
  //     console.log("Data stored successfully");
  //   } catch (error) {
  //     console.error("Error storing data:", error);
  //   }
  // };
  // retrieveProjects();

  return (
    <>
         <div className="flex justify-center mt-16">
        <div className="flex justify-start">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={addDuplicatedComponent}
            className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
          >
            Ajouter Appartement
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {duplicatedComponents.map((component, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Form
            number={component}
            componentIndex={index}
            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
            handleDeleteForm={handleDeleteForm} // Pass handleDeleteForm as prop
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      {duplicatedComponents.length > 0 && (
       <div className="flex justify-center mt-16">
       <div className="flex justify-start">
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={handleDeleteApparetment}
              className="focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900"
            >
              Supprimer Appartement
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
     <ToastContainer>
      
     </ToastContainer>
      <div className="flex justify-center mt-16">
        <div className="flex justify-start">
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={handleNextClick}
            className="focus:outline-none text-white bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-14 py-2.5 mr-4 mb-2 dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-green-800 text-center"
          >
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Form component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Form({ number, handleInputChange, handleDeleteForm }) {
  const [formCount, setFormCount] = useState(1);
  // console.log(formCount);
  const handleAddForm = () => {
    setFormCount((prevFormCount) => prevFormCount + 1);
   
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    if (formCount > 1) {
      handleDeleteForm(number, formCount);
      setFormCount(formCount - 1);
    }
  };

  const renderForms = () => {
    const forms = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= formCount; i++) {
      forms.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <p className="pr-4 mb-2">Porte {i}</p>
          <div className="flex flex-col mb-4 md:flex-row md:space-x-2">
            <input
              type="text"
              id={`height_${number}_${i}`}
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-black mb-2 md:mb-0 border-solid text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:text-white"
              placeholder="hauteur"
              required
              onChange={(e) =>
                handleInputChange(number, i, "height", e.target.value)
              }
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id={`width_${number}_${i}`}
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-black mb-2 md:mb-0 border-solid text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:text-white"
              placeholder="largeur"
              required
              onChange={(e) =>
                handleInputChange(number, i, "width", e.target.value)
              }
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id={`thickness_${number}_${i}`}
              className="bg-gray-50 border border-black mb-2 md:mb-0 border-solid text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:text-white"
              placeholder="epaisseur"
              required
              onChange={(e) =>
                handleInputChange(number, i, "thickness", e.target.value)
              }
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return forms;
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center mt-6">
      <form>
        <div className="flex justify-start mb-4"></div>
        <div className="flex justify-start mb-4">
          <h1>Appartement {number}</h1>
        </div>
        {renderForms()}
        <div className="flex justify-end mt-6">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
            onClick={handleAddForm}
          >
            Ajouter une porte
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900"
            onClick={handleDelete}
          >
            Supprimer une porte
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can any one help me pls